# How to catch an Exception which is thrown in a launched activity from your activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity

I have created Two Activities. One is MainActivity and another is ResultsActivity. ResultsActivity is launched from MainActivity  as shown below:

```
try {
        val intent = Intent(this, ResultsActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }catch (e:Exception) {
        Log.d("LOGTAG", "Caught exception")
    }
```

Now ResultsActivity throws an Exception on the click of a button as shown below:

```
fun throwException(view: View) {
    throw Exception("I am an exception")
}
```

But I am not able to catch this Exception inside MainActivity.

Note: I do not want to use **UncaughtExceptionHandler** here as ResultsActivity may be part of another application.

Can someone please help regarding how catch the exception thrown by ResultsActivity inside MainActivity?

Comment: There is no possible way. You can’t modify code in another application, and especially at runtime.